# Error inflating class fragment with Fragment library

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to test Fragment class, but somehow my program keeps incurring Error Inflating class fragment. I know that the question regarding this error has been repeatedly asked, but I find the answers not helpful. Since I do not need support for API < 11, I am using android.app.Activity library and android.app.Fragment library, which has getFragmentManager() method. I myself do not see any problem in my code, so can anyone help me out?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Fragment fragment1;
Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragment1 = new MainActivityFragment1();

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment1)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

MainAcitivityFragment1.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainActivityFragment1 extends Fragment {

public MainActivityFragment1() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
}
}
```

Fragment1.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1ST"
            android:onClick="onClick1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my logcat in case you need :

```
08-27 12:17:35.040    2290-2290/com.example.samplefragmentbasic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.samplefragmentbasic, PID: 2290
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.samplefragmentbasic/com.example.samplefragmentbasic.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at      `android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
        at com.example.samplefragmentbasic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:604)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5328)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.samplefragmentbasic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: you should post your log cat + your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Main activity is not extending the  FragmentActivity or any of its descendant classes. Try changing that to FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity ...as per your requirements.

Edit:- In this particular case --

When you are declaring the fragment in Activity layout file, you need to declare the android:name attribute in the   tag.

> android:name should point to the qualified name of the fragment class.

This tag only specifies the Fragment class to instantiate in the layout. So in your case the tag is missing and so the fragment layout is not inflated.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

Comment: May I ask why I need FragmentActivity instead of Activity or AppCompatActivity? Isn't FragmentActivity part of support library?

Comment: Yes you are right. FragmentActivity is not required, if you are not using support libraries. I have edited my answer, you just need to add Android:name pointing to your fragment class. Hope this helps.

Comment: I realized that I used <fragment> tag in MainActivity.xml but tried to inflate Fragment through MainActivity.java source code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@syk: **FYI**

Use this `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead `import android.app.Fragment;`. For your Fragment Section .

And Use `FragmentActivity` instead `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

And Import this

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but isn't support library for old platforms? Isn't FragmentActivity used for compatibility and Fragment used for newer platforms?https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html Here they did not use FragmentActivity.